# Generate Coupon Codes in CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob

I would like to generate a number of single use coupon codes - and judging by the wording at http://cartthrob.com/tour (next to Promotions heading) I can "generate coupon/voucher codes" but I can't see anywhere in the CP to do this.

Is it possible or do I have to manually add each coupon to the channel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have myself never used it, but could this addon be of some kind of help?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cartthrob-offers

Answer (score 0):

You must first define which channel(s) should be used for your coupons or discounts and set them up with the appropriate field types. Do this in the CartThrob settings menu of your CP.

You can then create the coupons or vouchers as entries in whichever channel you have set to be your discount or coupon channel.

Comment: Yeah, I have set all of that up and I understand how to make coupons one at a time - but what I want to know is if I need say 50 of the same coupons but all of them have different coupon codes and only one use - can I just do that at the same time or do I have to make each one myself?

Comment: I haven't used CT for a while but in that case I believe you'd need to make them yourself. However, you can create a single coupon code and limit it to one use per member. Obviously this would only work if your shoppers are signed in.

Comment: I see, thanks for the insight. I think that guest checkout is available so may need to find another solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the coupons yourself.

You could also make a single coupon that can be used only 50 times, if that's a viable option.